# How to update a property from within matlab class constructor

Tags: matlab, oop

I'm new to object oriented programming in matlab and am having some trouble modifying some of my properties from within my class constructor.  My class looks something like

```
classdef kENot

properties
    Sys;

end   
 methods
        function obj=kENot(Sys)
            %Constructor
            obj.Sys=Sys;        
            obj.eyePrime

        end

       function obj=eyePrime(obj)
           obj.Sys.IPrime=5
       end

 end
end
```

Then from the comand line I call that constructor as

```
Sys.Iprime=4;
classObj=kENot(Sys);
disp(classObj.Sys.Iprime)
```

And matlab prints 4.  What I want is for the value of classObj.Sys.Iprime to update during the call to obj.eyePrime in t he constructor, but that doesn't see to be happening.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, making a handle class is not the only way to solve this.

As long as `kENot` is not a handle class, you'll always have to assign the output of methods that change the object to the variable holding the instance.
In your current implementation `eyePrime` returns the modified `obj`. But you're not using the returned value.

So, you could change your constructor to:

```
function obj=kENot(Sys)
   %Constructor
   obj.Sys=Sys;        
   obj = obj.eyePrime();
end
```

Granted, this is pretty awkward syntax compared to all other object oriented programming languages and that's presumably why handle classes are favoured here.

As usual, there's pretty good documention from mathworks on this:

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html

Answer (score 1):

First I think that insead of `obj.Sys.IPrime=5` you should have `obj.Sys.Iprime=5`, i.e. small 'p'. Second, I think you need to make `handle` class.

```
classdef kENot < handle
    properties
        Sys;

    end   
     methods
            function obj=kENot(Sys)
                %Constructor
                obj.Sys=Sys;        
                obj.eyePrime();
            end

           function obj = eyePrime(obj)         
               obj.Sys.Iprime=5;
           end

     end
end
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can you please clarify what you mean by make handle?  What is the difference between "classdef kENot < handle" and just "classdef kENot"?  Thanks again!

Comment: Good catch on the uppercase/lowercase issue. Can you explain why you need `< handle`?